# How to Mock Geolocation for Multiple Pages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I would like to mock longitude and latitude, then click on a particular button, and have the page redirect me to another page with a Google map. However, Cypress does not remember my geolocations anymore.

This is correct, the marker is displayed on the map at my location when I am on the exact page where the Google Map is located:

```
const mockLocation = (latitude, longitude) => {
  return {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.stub(win.navigator.geolocation, "getCurrentPosition").callsFake(
        (cb, err) => {
          if (latitude && longitude) {
            return cb({ coords: { latitude, longitude } });
          }

          throw err({ code: 1 });
        },
      );
    },
  };
};

context.only(
  "Mocked geolocation",
  () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit(
        www.test.com,
        mockLocation(46.8182, 8.2275),
      );
    });

    it("Should display my location", () => {
      cy.get('.button').click(); <- button is on the same page where google map
      -- snip --
    });
  },
);
```

This is incorrect. After redirection, Cypress does not retain the latitude and longitude information, which results in the marker not being displayed on the map at my location:

```
context(
  "Mocked geolocation",
  { testIsolation: false },
  () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit(
        www.test.com,
        mockLocation(46.8182, 8.2275),
      );
    });

    it("Should display my location", () => {
      cy.get(".button").click(); <-- button redirects me to another page with google map
    });
  },
);
```

To confirm that this behavior is unrelated to the recent update where the testIsolation approach was modified, I disabled it by setting `{ testIsolation: false }`.

It looks like a bug or not well-designed software, but perhaps someone has a solution to make it more reliable.